# VB - Do actions in PictureBox in function of the button pressed with MouseEvents

Tags: vb.net, opencv

I am trying to do a functionality that I don't know if is possible to do. I have two programs that I want to mix.

The first one, allows me to draw points in the PictureBox by clicking on it with left click of the mouse, and I store the x,y coordenates in a label in the form:

```
Dim X As Integer
Dim Y As Integer
Dim localMousePosition As Point
Dim arrayXPoints(10) As Integer
Dim arrayYPoints(10) As Integer

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    PictureBox1.Image = Bitmap.FromFile("C:\Users\Dlozano\Desktop\Proyecto Calibración y Apunte M109\imágenes de prueba\negro640x480.png")

End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If MouseButtons = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left And PictureBox1.Image IsNot Nothing Then
        localMousePosition = PictureBox1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)
        X = localMousePosition.X
        Y = localMousePosition.Y
        PosicionRatonX.Text = X.ToString
        PosicionRatonY.Text = Y.ToString

        For i As Integer = 1 To 10
            If arrayXPoints(i) = Nothing Then
                arrayXPoints(i) = X
                arrayYPoints(i) = Y
                Exit For
            Else
                Continue For
            End If
        Next

        UpdatePositionLabels()
        DrawPoint(X, Y)

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub DrawPoint(X As Integer, Y As Integer)
    a = X
    b = Y

    Dim radius As Decimal = 10.0F
    Dim centerImage As New Point(a, b)
    Dim circle As CircleF = New CircleF(centerImage, 0)

    img = New Image(Of Bgr, Byte)(PictureBox1.Image)
    Dim imageCircle As Image(Of Bgr, Byte) = img

    imageCircle.Draw(circle, New Bgr(Color.Brown), 10)
    PictureBox1.Image = imageCircle.ToBitmap()
End Sub
```

Here I load a black image in the PictureBox, and when I click in the PictureBox, a red point is drawn, take the x,y coordenates and show it in the labels.

Ok, now I have developed another application, where I am able to draw in the PictureBox like if I am working in Paint:

```
Dim mustPaint As Boolean = False
Private lastPT As Point
Private signature As New GraphicsPath

Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseDown
    If Not IsNothing(signature) Then
        If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
            lastPT = New Point(e.X, e.Y)
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseMove
    If Not IsNothing(signature) Then
        If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
            Dim curPt As New Point(e.X, e.Y)
            signature.AddLine(lastPT, curPt)
            lastPT = curPt
            PictureBox1.Refresh()
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseUp
    If Not IsNothing(signature) Then
        If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
            signature.StartFigure()
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint
    If Not IsNothing(signature) Then
        e.Graphics.DrawPath(Pens.Black, signature)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub MouseEvent_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseDown
    mustPaint = True
End Sub

Private Sub MouseEvent_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseMove
    If mustPaint Then
        Dim graphic As Graphics = CreateGraphics()
        graphic.FillEllipse(New SolidBrush(Color.Red), e.X, e.Y, 10, 5)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub MouseEvent_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseUp
    mustPaint = False
End Sub
```

As you can notice, I am using the mouse events in both cases. What I want to achieve, is to put both programs in one, and using two buttons, be able to choose which functionality I want.

The problem I am having, is that I don't know how can I control the mouse events, because now is painting the point of the first program, and the line of the second one at the same time.

There is some way to say to the program that I want to use the mouse events for the first functionality, or for the second one, by choosing it using two buttons? (first button for the first functionality and second button for the second functionality) ..Is like mix two programs into one what I am trying to do..

Thanks a lot for any help you could give me!!

Comment: Why not just have a variable like `altFunctionality` as a `Boolean` that is set when you press your button, and then in each event handler check which you need to do? Is there anything you have actually tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
Dim first As Boolean
Dim second As Boolean

Private Sub Button1.CLick(...)Handles Button1.CLick
first = true
second = false
End Sub

Private Sub Button2.Click(...)Handles Button2.CLick
first = false
second = true
End Sub
```

After that, just add an `If first = true` and `ElseIf second = true` to adjust which code that will be applied.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I did this, by using two Checkbox:

```
Imports Emgu.CV
Imports Emgu.CV.Util
Imports Emgu.CV.Structure
Imports System.Drawing
Imports Emgu.CV.VideoSurveillance
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D

Public Class Form1

Dim img As Image(Of Bgr, Byte)
Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer
Dim X As Integer
Dim Y As Integer
Dim localMousePosition As Point
Dim arrayXPoints(10) As Integer
Dim arrayYPoints(10) As Integer

Dim mustPaint As Boolean = False
Private lastPT As Point
Private signature As New GraphicsPath

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    PictureBox1.Image = Bitmap.FromFile("C:\Users\Dlozano\Desktop\Proyecto Calibración y Apunte M109\imágenes de prueba\negro640x480.png")

End Sub

#Region "Point"
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    If CheckBoxPoint.Checked = True Then
        If MouseButtons = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left And PictureBox1.Image IsNot Nothing Then
            localMousePosition = PictureBox1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)
            X = localMousePosition.X
            Y = localMousePosition.Y
            PosicionRatonX.Text = X.ToString
            PosicionRatonY.Text = Y.ToString

            For i As Integer = 1 To 10
                If arrayXPoints(i) = Nothing Then
                    arrayXPoints(i) = X
                    arrayYPoints(i) = Y
                    Exit For
                Else
                    Continue For
                End If
            Next

            UpdatePositionLabels()
            DrawPoint(X, Y)

        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub DrawPoint(X As Integer, Y As Integer)
    a = X
    b = Y

    Dim radius As Decimal = 10.0F
    Dim centerImage As New Point(a, b)
    Dim circle As CircleF = New CircleF(centerImage, 0)

    img = New Image(Of Bgr, Byte)(PictureBox1.Image)
    Dim imageCircle As Image(Of Bgr, Byte) = img

    imageCircle.Draw(circle, New Bgr(Color.Brown), 10)
    PictureBox1.Image = imageCircle.ToBitmap()
End Sub

Private Sub UpdatePositionLabels()
    TextX1.Text = arrayXPoints(1)
    TextX2.Text = arrayXPoints(2)
    TextX3.Text = arrayXPoints(3)
    TextX4.Text = arrayXPoints(4)
    TextX5.Text = arrayXPoints(5)
    TextX6.Text = arrayXPoints(6)
    TextX7.Text = arrayXPoints(7)
    TextX8.Text = arrayXPoints(8)
    TextX9.Text = arrayXPoints(9)
    TextX10.Text = arrayXPoints(10)
    TextY1.Text = arrayYPoints(1)
    TextY2.Text = arrayYPoints(2)
    TextY3.Text = arrayYPoints(3)
    TextY4.Text = arrayYPoints(4)
    TextY5.Text = arrayYPoints(5)
    TextY6.Text = arrayYPoints(6)
    TextY7.Text = arrayYPoints(7)
    TextY8.Text = arrayYPoints(8)
    TextY9.Text = arrayYPoints(9)
    TextY10.Text = arrayYPoints(10)
End Sub

Private Sub processImage(bitmap As Bitmap)
    'Define a and b to determinate the position of the PictureBox
    a = PictureBox1.Width / 2 '- radius
    b = PictureBox1.Height / 2 '- radius

    Dim centerPictureBox2 As PointF = New PointF(a, b)


    Dim i As Integer
    Dim n As Integer

    'lock image
    Dim bitmapData As BitmapData
    bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(New Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bitmap.PixelFormat)

    'locating objects
    Dim blobCounter As AForge.Imaging.BlobCounter = New AForge.Imaging.BlobCounter
    blobCounter.FilterBlobs = True
    blobCounter.MinHeight = 5
    blobCounter.MinWidth = 5

    blobCounter.ProcessImage(bitmapData)
    Dim blobs As AForge.Imaging.Blob() = blobCounter.GetObjectsInformation()
    bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData)

    n = blobs.Length

    'step 3 - check objects' type and highlight
    Dim shapeChecker As AForge.Math.Geometry.SimpleShapeChecker = New AForge.Math.Geometry.SimpleShapeChecker()
    Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap)
    Dim yellowPen As Pen = New Pen(Color.Yellow, 2)

    For i = 0 To n
        If i < n Then
            Dim edgePoints As List(Of AForge.IntPoint) = blobCounter.GetBlobsEdgePoints(blobs(i))

            Dim center As AForge.DoublePoint
            Dim radius As Double

            'is circle?
            If shapeChecker.IsCircle(edgePoints, center, radius) Then
                'g.DrawEllipse(yellowPen, CType((center.X - radius), Decimal), CType((center.Y - radius), Decimal), CType((radius * 2), Decimal), CType((radius * 2), Decimal))
                Dim centerImage As New PointF(center.X, center.Y)
                Dim circle As CircleF = New CircleF(centerImage, radius)
                Dim pointOfCircle As CircleF = New CircleF(centerImage, 0)
                Dim pointOFCenterPictureBox2 As CircleF = New CircleF(centerPictureBox2, 0)

                Dim imageCircle As Image(Of Bgr, Byte) = img '.CopyBlank()
                Dim imagePointOfCircle As Image(Of Bgr, Byte) = img
                Dim imagePointOfPictureBox2 As Image(Of Bgr, Byte) = img

                imageCircle.Draw(circle, New Bgr(Color.Green), 10)
                imagePointOfCircle.Draw(pointOfCircle, New Bgr(Color.Green), 10)
                imagePointOfPictureBox2.Draw(pointOFCenterPictureBox2, New Bgr(Color.Yellow), 10)

                PictureBox1.Image = imageCircle.ToBitmap()
                PictureBox1.Image = imagePointOfCircle.ToBitmap()
                PictureBox1.Image = imagePointOfPictureBox2.ToBitmap()

            End If
        End If
    Next

    Clipboard.SetDataObject(bitmap)

End Sub

Private Sub ResetPositionLabels()
    For i As Integer = 1 To 10
        arrayXPoints(i) = 0
    Next

    For i As Integer = 1 To 10
        arrayYPoints(i) = 0
    Next
    UpdatePositionLabels()

End Sub

Private Sub DistanceBetweenCenters(centerImage As PointF)
    '    Dim centerIdeal As New PointF(a, b)
    '    Dim distanceBetween As Decimal

    '    If centerIdeal.X > centerImage.X And centerIdeal.Y > centerImage.Y Then
    '        distanceBetween = Math.Sqrt((Math.Abs(centerIdeal.X - centerImage.X) ^ 2) + (Math.Abs(centerIdeal.Y - centerImage.Y) ^ 2))
    '    ElseIf centerIdeal.X <= centerImage.X And centerIdeal.Y > centerImage.Y Then
    '        distanceBetween = Math.Sqrt((Math.Abs(centerImage.X - centerIdeal.X) ^ 2) + (Math.Abs(centerIdeal.Y - centerImage.Y) ^ 2))
    '    ElseIf centerIdeal.X > centerImage.X And centerIdeal.Y <= centerImage.Y Then
    '        distanceBetween = Math.Sqrt((Math.Abs(centerIdeal.X - centerImage.X) ^ 2) + (Math.Abs(centerImage.Y - centerIdeal.Y) ^ 2))
    '    ElseIf centerIdeal.X <= centerImage.X And centerIdeal.Y <= centerImage.Y Then
    '        distanceBetween = Math.Sqrt((Math.Abs(centerImage.X - centerIdeal.X) ^ 2) + (Math.Abs(centerImage.Y - centerIdeal.Y) ^ 2))
    '    End If

    '    TextBox1.Text = "Dist. centros: " & distanceBetween
    '    TextBoxCentroPantalla.Text = "Centro pantalla: " & a & ", " & b
    '    TextBoxWidth.Text = "Width: " & PictureBox2.Width
    '    TextBoxHeight.Text = "Height: " & PictureBox2.Height
End Sub

Private Sub RestartButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RestartButton.Click
    Timer1.Stop()
    PictureBox1.Image = Nothing
    PictureBox1.Image = Bitmap.FromFile("C:\Users\Dlozano\Desktop\Proyecto Calibración y Apunte M109\imágenes de prueba\negro640x480.png")
    PosicionRatonX.Text = Nothing
    PosicionRatonY.Text = Nothing
    ResetPositionLabels()

End Sub
Private Sub CloseButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CloseButton.Click
    Close()
End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CargaFoto.Click
    ' Show the Open File dialog. If the user clicks OK, load the
    ' picture that the user chose.
    If (OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
        PictureBox1.Load(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
    End If

    Dim imgbm As Bitmap = PictureBox1.Image
    img = New Image(Of Bgr, Byte)(imgbm)

    processImage(PictureBox1.Image)

    Timer1.Start()

End Sub

Private Sub CheckBoxLine_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBoxLine.CheckedChanged
    If CheckBoxLine.Checked = True Then
        CheckBoxPoint.Checked = False
        CheckBoxPoint.Enabled = False
    Else
        CheckBoxPoint.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBoxPoint_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBoxPoint.CheckedChanged
    If CheckBoxObjective.Checked = True Then
        CheckBoxLine.Checked = False
        CheckBoxLine.Enabled = False
    Else
        CheckBoxLine.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub

#End Region

#Region "Line"
Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseDown
    If CheckBoxLine.Checked = True Then
        If Not IsNothing(signature) Then
            If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
                lastPT = New Point(e.X, e.Y)
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseMove
    If CheckBoxLine.Checked = True Then
        If Not IsNothing(signature) Then
            If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
                Dim curPt As New Point(e.X, e.Y)
                signature.AddLine(lastPT, curPt)
                lastPT = curPt
                PictureBox1.Refresh()
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseUp
    If CheckBoxLine.Checked = True Then
        If Not IsNothing(signature) Then
            If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
                signature.StartFigure()
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint
    If CheckBoxLine.Checked = True Then
        If Not IsNothing(signature) Then
            e.Graphics.DrawPath(Pens.Black, signature)
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub MouseEvent_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseDown
    If CheckBoxLine.Checked = True Then
        mustPaint = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub MouseEvent_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseMove
    If CheckBoxLine.Checked = True Then
        If mustPaint Then
            Dim graphic As Graphics = CreateGraphics()
            graphic.FillEllipse(New SolidBrush(Color.Red), e.X, e.Y, 10, 5)
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub MouseEvent_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseUp
    If CheckBoxLine.Checked = True Then
        mustPaint = False
    End If
End Sub

#End Region
End Class
```

I post all the code if can help someone.
I have done this using another project, where I load an image from a path in my computer, an all black image. After I load an image, the code check if there is any circle in the image, and put that image in white and draw the circle and the center of that circle. This is what my mother program does. The program has three buttons, one to load the picture, another one to reset the form, and another one to close the form

What I have added is the checkbox to control the mouse events. Inside both regions, I check if one of the checkbox is enabled. If it is, I disable the other checkbox, and inside the functions that has the functionality I want to do with the mouse events, I ask if the checkbox is clicked. If it is, the function does its purpose.

Also I am registering the coordenates of the points I am putting on the PictureBox.

I hope this could be useful for someone, and also if I have to explain something, let me know.

My final solution is very similar that @TGamer said. Thanks for your response because it help me a lot!